# How to bind multiple Power BI datasets to a single Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a user name logging into the Web Application.

I am using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and ASP.NET webform to run the Web Application with Power BI embedded reports.

I am trying to code to pass Server Name and Database name based on the user logged in to Power BI embedded config.

How to pass server name and database name to Power BI Embedded config?

Tried to test the application flow with Import Data Sets using following things, but the Power BI Report is not getting loaded in HTML div element. Its giving "Power BI Loading logo" in the embed div and then showing message as "Power BI content is not available"

Application Flow:

1. Power BI workspace has One Report and Two Datasets
2. Following is the Token generation code in .NET

```
            // Generate an embed token and populate embed variables
            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(Configurations.ApiUrl), Authentication.GetTokenCredentials()))
            //using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(Configurations.ApiUrl), Authentication.m_tokenCredentials))
            {
                var report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(new Guid(Configurations.WorkspaceId), new Guid(ddlReport.SelectedValue));
                                                           
                var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(username: appLoginUserName, new List<string> { userDatasetId.ToString() });
                
                // Effective Identity
                var rolesList = new List<string>();
                rolesList.Add("Tenant");
                rls.Roles = rolesList;

                // Create list of datasets
                var v2DatasetID = new List<Guid>();
                v2DatasetID.Add(userDatasetId);

                // Create list of Effective Identities
                var v2rls = new List<EffectiveIdentity>();
                v2rls.Add(rls);

                // Create a request for getting Embed token 
                // This method works only with new Power BI V2 workspace experience
                var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequestV2(

                    reports: new List<GenerateTokenRequestV2Report>() { new GenerateTokenRequestV2Report(report.Id) },

                    datasets: v2DatasetID.Select(datasetId => new GenerateTokenRequestV2Dataset(datasetId.ToString())).ToList(),

                    identities: v2rls,

                    targetWorkspaces: null


                );

                // Generate Embed token
                var getToken = client.EmbedToken.GenerateToken(tokenRequest);
                

                // Populate embed variables (to be passed client-side)
                //embedToken = tokenResponse.Token;
                embedToken = getToken.ToString();
                embedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
                reportId = report.Id;

            }
```

3. Following is the Power BI embed configuration with dynamic dataset:

```
        <script>
            // Read embed token
            var embedToken = "<% =this.embedToken %>";

            // Read embed URL
            var embedUrl = "<% = this.embedUrl %>";

            // Read report Id
            var reportId = "<% = this.reportId %>";

            // Read dataset Id
            var userDatasetId = "<% = this.userDatasetId %>";

            // Get models (models contains enums)
            var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

            // Embed configuration is used to describe what and how to embed
            // This object is used when calling powerbi.embed
            // It can also includes settings and options such as filters
            var config = {
                type: 'report',
                tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                accessToken: embedToken,
                embedUrl: embedUrl,
                id: reportId,   
                datasetId: userDatasetId, // The dataset id that you want the report to use 
                settings: {
                    filterPaneEnabled: true,
                    navContentPaneEnabled: true,
                    extensions: [
                        {
                            command: {
                                name: "cmdShowValue",
                                title: "Show Value in MessageBox",
                                selector: {
                                    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#visualSelector",
                                    visualName: "VisualContainer7" // Sales and Avg Price by Month visual
                                },
                                extend: {
                                    visualContextMenu: {
                                        title: "Show Value in MessageBox"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                }
            };

            // Embed the report within the div element
            var report = powerbi.embed(embedDiv, config);
            
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. These are **report wide settings** and you are asking how two different users, which are viewing **the same report** simultaneously, to connect to a different data sources. You must either deploy as many report are needed and choose which one to embed, or build one report using all the data sources, and then [filter the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters) based on the currently logged in used.

Otherwise, the direct answer to your question is to [rebind the report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/rebindreportingroup) or to [change the datasource of the dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updatedatasourcesingroup).

Comment: Thank you Andrey for the reply. I am trying to explore the "One Report and Multiple Data Soources" option by referring this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/bind-report-datasets) .Once done will let you know.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, I have added the code in the question.